# what does "it is a little hard to follow" mean?

Tags: meaning

I want to know what does **"it is a little hard to follow"** mean ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A context would help here. Where did you see/hear that sentence?

Comment: It means it’s not easy to understand.  Unless you’re talking about a map.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, but also consider our sister site, English Language Learners.

Comment: "Hard to follow" is an idiom meaning "difficult to understand".

Comment: @Jim, or if you are talking about performing after a really good act.

Comment: you're right. I got it, but why don't you put your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"hard to follow" means something is difficult to understand.

Such as many would consider calculus, "hard to follow", because they personally find it difficult and confusing.